# Render ajax data on datatables stuck on progress with an error "TypeError: data is undefined"

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, datatable, datatables

I am trying to populate my data table with data I have populated with codeigniter..

Here is the object am getting

```
[{"checkbox":"<input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' id='expense_'185' value='185'\/>","expense_id":"185","category":"Others","description":"Payment Of Service For Sep $ October 2018","amount":"ksh.2,000","name":"Caroline Zachaeus","date":"27 Nov 2018"}, {"checkbox":"<input type='checkbox' name='chk[]' id='expense_'185' value='185'\/>","expense_id":"185","category":"Others","description":"Payment Of Service For Sep $ October 2018","amount":"ksh.2,000","name":"Caroline Zachaeus","date":"27 Nov 2018"}]
```

When am rendering, it says

> TypeError: data is undefined

Here is my ajax code

```
 var table = $("#datatable").DataTable({

        "columnDefs" : [{"targets" : [ 7,0] , "orderable" : false},

                        {"targets" : [1], "visible": false}, 
        ],


        "fixedHeader": true,

        "aLengthMenu": [[25, 50, 100, 200, -1], [25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]],

        "iDisplayLength": 25,

        "order": [],

        'processing': true,
        'serverSide': true,
        'serverMethod': 'get',
        'ajax': {
            'url':'<?=base_url()?>index.php/expenses/data'  
        },

        "columns" : [
            "checkbox",
            "expense_id",
            "category",
            "description",
            "amount",
            "name",
            "date",
            "action",
        ],  
    })
```

Here is my page screenshot 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

where is your controller function 
i think you are posting data from controller json type 
and you have to set ajax datatype:'json'
then it will work for you